flask login_user doen't carry over when redirecting, defaults back to anonymous user
I have a aplication that involves logging in a user so they can perform actions like create a post but my login manager is not working as i expected
I am defining my flask login manager in my config file like so:
 #login manager
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app) 

I am logging in a user in a login page like so:
   login_user(user, remember=True) #user is a user from the USer table and is queried and checked to exist before this is ran
   session['authentication_attempts'] = 0
   flash('Login Successful', category='success')
   return redirect(url_for('accounts.account')) 


but after redirecting the 'current_user' is reset to an anonymous user.
My user database looks like this:
'''
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # User authentication information.
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    # User information
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    #MFA info
    MFAkey = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    MFA_enabled = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False)
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False)

    # User posts
    posts = db.relationship("Post", order_by=Post.id, 
back_populates="user")

def __init__(self, email, firstname, lastname, phone, password, 
    MFAkey, MFA_enabled):
    
    self.email = email
    self.firstname = firstname
    self.lastname = lastname
    self.phone = phone
    self.password = password
    self.MFAkey = MFAkey
    self.MFA_enabled = MFA_enabled
    self.is_active = True

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.filter(user_id == id).first()

'''
From testing I know that other attributes of the session carry over and that the user is correctly logged in before the redirect but not after. It is also the same issue if I redirect to any page
Any help is much appreciated

can you share more of your code? specifically about this part:
   login_user(user, remember=True) #user is a user from the USer table and is queried and checked to exist before this is ran
   session['authentication_attempts'] = 0
   flash('Login Successful', category='success')
   return redirect(url_for('accounts.account')) 

you are doing those things, but never setting a cookie to the user from what i can see, but wihtout more code is impossible to understand

@JoseAngelSanchez I don't define any cookies in my code from the resources I read they did not specify that you must create cookies.

You have defined a column is_active for your class User. Unfortunately, the UserMixin used has an attribute with the same name is_active, which is therefore overridden. I think you should rename your database column so that the name collision is resolved and it works as desired.
Another problem exists within the callback load_user() for the LoginManager. The database query does not work.
If you use User.query.filter(...).first(), unlike .filter_by(...), it is necessary to specify the column along with the class name of the model. The following example shows you some examples of how you can use the query.
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    # return User.query.filter(User.id == user_id).first()
    # or
    # return User.query.filter_by(id = user_id).first()
    # or
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


thank you I did not realize that 'UserMixin' did this. However this did not fix my issue

@JB1511 I updated my answer and hope this resolves your issue.

Changing the query fixed it thanks for your help!
